# How to config Scss and purgeCss in Next js custom postCSS config

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, postcss, css-purge

I am using `Scss` and `Bootstrap` for designing my project. In order to remove unused `Css` with `purgeCss` , I have customized my `postcss.config.js` file like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
    [
      "postcss-preset-env",
      {
        autoprefixer: {
          flexbox: "no-2009",
        },
        stage: 3,
        features: {
          "custom-properties": false,
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
      {
        content: [
          "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        ],
        defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
        safelist: ["html", "body"],
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

The problem is that `postCss` is ignoring my `Scss` files and not showing styles.
How can I add `Scss` to `postcss.config.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem come from `@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss`.
You can delete it.

```
 [
      "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
      {
        content: [
          "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        ],
        defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
        safelist: ["html", "body"],
      },
    ],
```

And then work scss again. Or you can change setting about content.